# Webpack failed to compile

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-hot-loader, babel-loader

I have just started to learn React and I'm implementing it with Webpack.

Here are the `devDependencies` from my `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
  "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
  "react-scripts": "1.0.7",
  "serve": "^5.2.4",
  "webpack": "^3.0.0",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.0"
},
```

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + "/src",
    entry: './index.js',

    output: {
        filename: "index.js",
        path: __dirname + '/dist'
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loaders: ["react-hot-loader", "babel-loader"],
        }
        ],
    },
}
```

Here is `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react"
  ]
}
```

Now when I run `npm start` it raises this error

```
ERROR in ./src/index.css
Module parse failed: /home/tps/ReactApps/login-app/src/index.css Unexpected token (1:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| body {
|   margin: 0;
|   padding: 0;
@ ./src/index.js 21:0-22
@ multi ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 webpack/hot/dev-server ./index.js

ERROR in ./src/App.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './notFound' in '/home/tps/ReactApps/login-app/src'
@ ./src/App.js 33:16-37
@ ./src/index.js
@ multi ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 webpack/hot/dev-server ./index.js

ERROR in ./src/App.css
Module parse failed: /home/tps/ReactApps/login-app/src/App.css Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| .App {
|   text-align: center;
| }
@ ./src/App.js 19:0-20
@ ./src/index.js
@ multi ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 webpack/hot/dev-server ./index.js
```

Please help me to solve this.

**Edit 1:**

`webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + "/src",
  entry: './index.js',

  output: {
    filename: "index.js",
    path: __dirname + '/dist'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ["react-hot-loader", "babel-loader"],
      }
    ],
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

`package.json`

```
 "devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
  "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
  "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
  "react-scripts": "1.0.7",
  "serve": "^5.2.4",
  "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
  "webpack": "^3.0.0",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.0"
},
```

Comment: The fix for me was so simple. `npm install`. Not really worth an answer, but it worked for me when I got this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a css-loader to your webpack config in order to be able to import css files.

`npm install --save-dev css-loader style-loader`

and add the following to the`loaders` array in your webpack config:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
}
```

Check this for more info: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader.

Edit: You're using both loaders and rules. They're basically the same thing.
Check this for more info: https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#module-loaders-is-now-module-rules

Try this webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + "/src",
  entry: './index.js',

  output: {
    filename: "index.js",
    path: __dirname + '/dist'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ["react-hot-loader", "babel-loader"],
      },       
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

Comment: Give me error
```ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module parse failed: /home/tps/ReactApps/login-app/src/index.js Unexpected token (7:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import './index.css';
| 
| ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
| registerServiceWorker();
| 
 @ multi ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 webpack/hot/dev-server ./index.js
```

Comment: inside index.js you are importing a css file and webpack is unable to handle it, this is what the error means.

Comment: Did you install the css loader? update your question with the new webpack.config.js and the new package.json

Comment: did you check my edit to the answer? Add the css-loader rule to the same `loaders` array instead of adding it to a new `rules` array.

Comment: Thanks, it works.
Actually I was try above solution before, and error was different, and I think error was about webpack, so I was ignore the error.

Thanks again :)